How to use Vue Vapor mode beta?
I would like to test out locally new Vue Vapor mode. It is currently beta version with no release yet, but I am keen on to try it out. My question is, how can I do this?
I have my personal Vue3 project, int it I have added a git submodule of core-vapor. This submodule is in the root of the project.
Then I have edited vite.config.ts:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), VueDevTools()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@vue/core-vapor': path.resolve(__dirname, 'core-vapor/packages/vue-vapor')
    }
  }
})

Afterwards, I have created a pnpm link --global from inside the submodule. I can see it registered globally:
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

core-vapor@3.5.0-beta.1 /home/gmo/projects/0703_Genesis_FE/core-vapor (PRIVATE)

devDependencies:
@babel/parser 7.25.3                magic-string 0.30.11                
@babel/types 7.25.2                 markdown-table 3.0.3    
...

Now it should be possible to use the vapor mode inside my project. I was trying to apply it via: import { createApp } from '@vue/core-vapor' or this import { createVaporApp } from '@vue/core-vapor'. But it gives me this syntax error:
SyntaxError: The requested module '/core-vapor/packages/vue-vapor/index.mjs' does not provide an export named 'createApp'

The same error is for the createVaporApp case.
What am I doing wrong? How should I link my submodule into my project? Should I somehow build the submodule? As far as I know, this should be the pnpm link´s job. For me it seems me like a export problem (from the core-vapor).
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
